# Python class __call__ function is not vectorized

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to plot a function using the `__call__` dunder for a custom class

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class F:
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self._n = n
        self._m = m

    def __call__(self, x):
        return math.sin(self._n * x) * math.cos(self._m * x)

u = F(1,1)
v = F(1,1)

x_array = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)

u_array = u(x_array)
v_array = v(x_array)

plt.plot(u_array, v_array)
plt.show()
```

However, executing the code, i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F.py", line 18, in <module>
    u_array = u(x_array)
  File "F.py", line 11, in __call__
    return math.sin(self._n * x) * math.cos(self._m * x)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

It seems that the call `u_array = u(x_array)` sends the entire x_array to the function, instead of doing it in a vectorized way.

Please help

Comment: Why would you expect it to *not* send the whole thing to the function? It's an object. It gets passed as one.

Comment: Because this:

```py
def y(t):
    return A * np.exp(-gamma*t) * np.cos( np.sqrt( k / m ) * t )

t_array = np.linspace(start, end, n)
y_array = y(t_array)
```
has worked for me before. i dont know why this acts different

Comment: That function is still receiving the whole array. It's just that you're using simple math and `numpy`-array-aware functions, so each operation/function call processes the whole array at a time. `math.sin` and `math.cos` aren't `numpy`-array-aware; they take one value at a time. Did you mean to use the `numpy` equivalent functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `numpy` vectorized functions instead of those from `math`:

```
def __call__(self, x):
    return np.sin(self._n * x) * np.cos(self._m * x)
```